# Pandas: Insert column according to index values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have the following example data

```
In [1]: table[['id', 'age']]
Out[1]: 
   id  age
0   1   12
1   2   13
2   3   14
3   4   15
4   5   16
5   6   17
6   7   18
7   8  NaN
8   9   20
```

ad the following `np.array`

```
In [2]: data
Out[2]: 
array([[  1.,   3.,  21.],
       [  2.,   4.,  21.],
       [  3.,   5.,  22.],
       [  4.,   5.,  22.],
       [  5.,   4.,   2.]])
```

and would like to concatenate the `data` to the `table` according to the `id`.

For example the result should look like:

```
id  age
0   1   12  3     21
1   2   13  4     21 
2   3   14  5     22
3   4   15  5     22
4   5   16  4     2
5   6   17  
6   7   18  
7   8  NaN  
8   9   20
```

I can loop over `zip(table,data)` and work line by line, but I thought it could be done in a more *concise* way

Comment: You state it should be inserted according to 'id' but your result shows it aligning to the index, also can you post code to reproduce your data and df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this as an answer according to your text desired result rather than your posted result df, I can edit it easily if that's what you really want.

Firstly construct a df from the np array and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge) this. We merge the left side on 'id' and the right side on column '0' and perform an outer merge, we have to drop the '0' column as it's superfluous to what we want:

```
In [261]:

data = np.array([[  1.,   3.,  21.],
       [  2.,   4.,  21.],
       [  3.,   5.,  22.],
       [  4.,   5.,  22.],
       [  5.,   4.,   2.]])
data
Out[261]:
array([[  1.,   3.,  21.],
       [  2.,   4.,  21.],
       [  3.,   5.,  22.],
       [  4.,   5.,  22.],
       [  5.,   4.,   2.]])
In [265]:

data_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_df
Out[265]:
   0  1   2
0  1  3  21
1  2  4  21
2  3  5  22
3  4  5  22
4  5  4   2
In [268]:

df.merge(data_df, left_on='id', right_on=0, how='outer').drop(0, axis=1)
Out[268]:
   id  age   1   2
0   1   12   3  21
1   2   13   4  21
2   3   14   5  22
3   4   15   5  22
4   5   16   4   2
5   6   17 NaN NaN
6   7   18 NaN NaN
7   8  NaN NaN NaN
8   9   20 NaN NaN
```

Comment: haha I am trying to answer this with the same approach, but that you're quicker